# using MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage to save image，but the datetime is 1970.1.1

Tags: android, image

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, System.currentTimeMillis() + "", "description");
```

I don't know where to edit the date

Comment: only can use bitmap to save image

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will provide you deate and time stamp on your file you are storing in external sotrage.

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());


File mediaFile;
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator+ "IMG_" + timeStamp + getNextNumber() +".jpg"); 
return mediaFile; 


public String getNextNumber(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int default = 0;
    int value = prefs.getInt("PICTURE_COUNT", default); 
    prefs.edit().putInt("PICTURE_COUNT", ++value).commit();
    return convertToDesiredFormat(value);
} 

String convertToDesiredFormat(int value){
      String toReturn = null;
      if (value > 99)
         toReturn = Integer.toString(value);
      else if (value > 9)
         toReturn = "0" + Integer.toString(value);
      else if (value >= 0)
         toReturn = "00" + Integer.toString(value);
      return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: thank you，but I just want to use bitmap,don't want to create a temp file